# How to modify request text in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I can't think of a good title I'm so sorry but I need help.

I have a field that is added by jquery depending on how many questions are present in the database, so for example I have 3 questions in the db i will have 3 answer fields too, it will look like this:

answer_1
answer_2
answer_3

since i am not sure how many questions there can be, i need to loop the $request->answer_1, 2 and 3 in the controller to store the answers. but i'm not sure how to do it. I have tried:

```
for($i = 0; $i < total.count.of.answers; i++){
    $x = $i + 1;
    $answer = new Answer;
    $answer->answer = $request->answer_{$x};
    $answer->save();
}
```

but not working. How do I achieve this?

(note i can already send the answers to the backend using jquery, problem is only how i can pull it in the controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd group my inputs as such:

```
<form action="/submit" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="answers[]">
    <input type="text" name="answers[]">
    <input type="text" name="answers[]">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then, in my controller, I would be able to loop through the answers by doing the following:

```
foreach($request->answers as $answer) {
    Answer::create(['answer' => $answer]); 
}
```

This is just an example, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel:** save multiple records in database.

```
foreach($request->all as $value){       
   $answer = new Answer;
   $answer->answer = $value->answer;
   $answer->save();
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code. Additionally, are you sure about using `all`? What if other fields are present in the same request?